# Symfony2 Twig loading templates on shared server

Tags: symfony

Symfony2 Twig loading templates on shared server.

I am having some trouble telling twig which template to load. When I declare: return `FrontendHomeBundle:Page:index.html.twig` I get the following error:

```
Unable to find template "FrontendHomeBundle:Page:index.html.twig".
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
3 linked Exceptions:Twig_Error_Loader » InvalidArgumentException » InvalidArgumentException »
```

Comment: Are the messages of the 3 linked Exceptions helpful or not?

Comment: Thank you greg0ire for reply, but i'm new in symfony2, if i ran this script on my local machine then it is working, but when i ran this script on shared server then i got this message.

Comment: Every exception comes with a message. You're showing us the message of the main exception. Click on the ">>" signs to get to the linked Exception and see their messages.

Comment: This is what I am getting.
PART-1
Twig_Error_Loader » 
in kernel.root_dir/cache/dev/classes.php at line 2261  -+

            try {
                return $this->cache[$key] = $this->locator->locate($template->getPath(), $currentPath);
            } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Unable to find template "%s" : "%s".', $template, $e->getMessage()), 0, $e);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: InvalidArgumentException » 
in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 703  -+

                return $first && $isResource ? $files[0] : $files;
            }
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Unable to find file "%s".', $name));
        }

Comment: InvalidArgumentException » 
in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 703  -+

                return $first && $isResource ? $files[0] : $files;
            }
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Unable to find file "%s".', $name));
        }
        
CRITICAL - InvalidArgumentException: Unable to find template "FrontendHomeBundle:Page:index.html.twig". (uncaught exception) at /home/xyz/public_html/abc/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/TwigEngine.php line 123

Comment: Where is your template file located ?

Comment: Not very helpful messages... please answer Adrien's question.

Comment: src/Frontend/HomeBundle/Resources/views/page/index.html.twig

Comment: @pacific what do you get if you rename the `page` dir to `Page`?

Comment: @ Wouter J: I rename the page dir to Page and it works for me, thank you very much for helping me.